# Recursive loop, multiple conditions in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML document with multiple instances and types of children within an element type, and need to display them both in order and with different formatting for each child type.

I've tried different combinations of `for-each` and conditional `choose` loops, but with no luck.

XML Segment:

```
<PLAY>  
<PERSONAE>
<TITLE>Dramatis Personae</TITLE>

<PERSONA>CLAUDIUS, king of Denmark. </PERSONA>
<PERSONA>HAMLET, son to the late, and nephew to the present king.</PERSONA>
<PERSONA>POLONIUS, lord chamberlain. </PERSONA>
<PERSONA>HORATIO, friend to Hamlet.</PERSONA>
<PERSONA>LAERTES, son to Polonius.</PERSONA>
<PERSONA>LUCIANUS, nephew to the king.</PERSONA>

<PGROUP>
<PERSONA>VOLTIMAND</PERSONA>
<PERSONA>CORNELIUS</PERSONA>
<PERSONA>ROSENCRANTZ</PERSONA>
<PERSONA>GUILDENSTERN</PERSONA>
<PERSONA>OSRIC</PERSONA>
<GRPDESCR>courtiers.</GRPDESCR>
</PGROUP>

<PERSONA>A Gentleman</PERSONA>
<PERSONA>A Priest. </PERSONA>

<PGROUP>
<PERSONA>MARCELLUS</PERSONA>
<PERSONA>BERNARDO</PERSONA>
<GRPDESCR>officers.</GRPDESCR>
</PGROUP>
```

XSL:

```
<h2><xsl:value-of select="PLAY/PERSONAE/TITLE" /></h2>
<xsl:for-each select="PLAY/PERSONAE/node()">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="PERSONA">
            <xsl:value-of select="PERSONA" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="PGROUP">
            <xsl:for-each select="PERSONA">
                <xsl:value-of select="PERSONA" />
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:value-of select="PGROUP" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise />
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Output

```
Dramatis Personae
VOLTIMANDMARCELLUS
```

Expected (Hopeful) Output

```
Dramatis Personae

CLAUDIUS, king of Denmark.

HAMLET, son to the late, and nephew to the present king.

POLONIUS, lord chamberlain.
HORATIO, friend to Hamlet.
LAERTES, son to Polonius.
LUCIANUS, nephew to the king.

VOLTIMAND
CORNELIUS
ROSENCRANTZ
GUILDENSTERN
OSRIC

A Gentleman
A Priest.

MARCELLUS
BERNARDO


FRANCISCO, a soldier.
REYNALDO, servant to Polonius.
Players.
Two Clowns, grave-diggers.
FORTINBRAS, prince of Norway.
A Captain.
English Ambassadors.
GERTRUDE, queen of Denmark, and mother to Hamlet.
OPHELIA, daughter to Polonius.

Lords, Ladies, Officers, Soldiers, Sailors, Messengers, and other Attendants.
```

Ghost of Hamlet's Father.

Every time, it either returns only the very first PERSONA child it parses, or it returns the first two PGROUP/PERSONA children. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please show us the expected output. Having a well-formed XML as the input would also be helpful.

Comment: The XML input is a raw version of the ENTIRE text of a play. Suffice it to say that the root is `<PLAY>`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k XSL can output text, so the above could well be the "expected output".

Comment: @fluffywarthog Your stylesheet seems to be designed to output HTML, yet you show text as the expected output. That's confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something more like:

```
<xsl:template match="PERSONAE">
<xsl:value-of select="TITLE"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="PERSONA|PGROUP"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="PGROUP">
<xsl:apply-templates select="PERSONA"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="PERSONA">
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

Your:

```
<xsl:for-each select="PLAY/PERSONAE/node()">
```

is a just selecting the first node child of each PERSONAE

Comment: "*just selecting the first node child of each PERSONAE*" I am afraid you are mistaken about that. It selects all node children of each PERSONAE.

Comment: I wasn't aware you could generate a template without an external template or namespace referenced. This looks unbelievably easy now.

Answer (score 1):

If I am guessing correctly, you want an HTML output, not text. Here's a way you could achieve a result that, when rendered, will look like what you posted:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/PLAY">
    <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </body>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="PERSONAE">
    <h2>
        <xsl:value-of select="TITLE" />
    </h2>
    <div>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="PERSONA | PGROUP"/>
    </div>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="PERSONA">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <br/>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="PGROUP">
    <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="PERSONA"/>
    </p>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the following test input:

```
<PLAY>
   <PERSONAE>
      <TITLE>Dramatis Personae</TITLE>
      <PERSONA>CLAUDIUS, king of Denmark. </PERSONA>
      <PERSONA>HAMLET, son to the late, and nephew to the present king.</PERSONA>
      <PERSONA>POLONIUS, lord chamberlain. </PERSONA>
      <PERSONA>HORATIO, friend to Hamlet.</PERSONA>
      <PERSONA>LAERTES, son to Polonius.</PERSONA>
      <PERSONA>LUCIANUS, nephew to the king.</PERSONA>
      <PGROUP>
         <PERSONA>VOLTIMAND</PERSONA>
         <PERSONA>CORNELIUS</PERSONA>
         <PERSONA>ROSENCRANTZ</PERSONA>
         <PERSONA>GUILDENSTERN</PERSONA>
         <PERSONA>OSRIC</PERSONA>
         <GRPDESCR>courtiers.</GRPDESCR>
      </PGROUP>
      <PERSONA>A Gentleman</PERSONA>
      <PERSONA>A Priest. </PERSONA>
      <PGROUP>
         <PERSONA>MARCELLUS</PERSONA>
         <PERSONA>BERNARDO</PERSONA>
         <GRPDESCR>officers.</GRPDESCR>
      </PGROUP>
   </PERSONAE>
</PLAY>
```

the result will be:

```
<body>
   <h2>Dramatis Personae</h2>
<p>CLAUDIUS, king of Denmark. <br>HAMLET, son to the late, and nephew to the present king.<br>POLONIUS, lord chamberlain. <br>HORATIO, friend to Hamlet.<br>LAERTES, son to Polonius.<br>LUCIANUS, nephew to the king.<br><p>VOLTIMAND<br>CORNELIUS<br>ROSENCRANTZ<br>GUILDENSTERN<br>OSRIC<br></p>A Gentleman<br>A Priest. <br><p>MARCELLUS<br>BERNARDO<br></p></p>
</body>
```

rendered as:

[image]